# How can I import .fbx animations into Blender?

Tags: animation, armature, import, .fbx, actions

I was just examining the Unity [3D Game Kit](https://assetstore.unity.com/packages/templates/tutorials/3d-game-kit-lite-135162) for best practices and was hoping to import the Ellen .fbx model with animations into Blender.

While Ellen herself imports fairly well...
[image]

...her animations are stored as a series of separate .fbx files in the directory, \Art\Animations\AnimationClips\Characters\Ellen .
[image]

Attempting to import these results in another copy of the Ellen mesh, along with another armature, and no obvious animations.

Can anybody tell me how to best import a .fbx character with animations into Blender? Many thanks in advance.